# Filtering a Datagridview based on a text box

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I'm new to C# and am having trouble with filtering a data grid on the Text changed event of a textbox. Instead of it looking for a value in the column which is called BarCode. It seems to be looking at the column names. This is the code I have so far from tutorials adapted to suit my purpose.

```
     private void Barcode_txtBx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data = "Select * from BookInTable";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(data, connection));
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        DataView DV = new DataView();
        DV.Table = ds.Tables[0];
        DV.RowFilter = "BarCode = " + Barcode_txtBx.Text.Trim();
        dGrid.DataSource = DV;
    }
```

Comment: `DV.RowFilter = "BarCode = '" + Barcode_txtBx.Text.Trim() + "'";` You need to wrap the value withing single quotes as per the SQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But how do I go about saying Barcode like Barcode_txtBx.Text

Comment: To explain better. In access with the LIKE command you could filter so that even if you just put the letter a in the textbox it would filter to all records starting with a and as you typed the list of records got shorter.

Comment: `DV.RowFilter = "BarCode LIKE '" + Barcode_txtBx.Text.Trim() + "%'"`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Chetan. I got up to DV.RowFilter = "BarCode LIKE '" + Barcode_txtBx.Text.Trim() + "'" But this seemed to just do the same as = instead of LIKE. This is because I was missing the %.

Comment: Yes... Like is not of much use if you are not using `%`. So if you want to use LIKE in your query you better use `%` around the the value to be searched. But use it wisely else performance will degrade if number rows are more.